# RequireJS load order mystery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, requirejs

I can't seem to get my dependancies to load first. Here is a screen shot of the load order which is completely wrong:

[image]

Kendo should be one of the first to load after Jquery, as transaction-grid.js depends on kendo and jquery.

Here is my requireJS line:

```
HTML::script('js/requirejs.js', array('data-main' => '/js/main.js'))
```

With config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": [
            "jquery"
        ],
        'bootstrap': [
            'bootstrap'
        ],
        'kendo': [
            'kendo'
        ],
        handlebars: 'handlebars'
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps :["jquery"]
        },
        "kendo": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
})
```

The transaction-grid.js file starts with:

```
require(['jquery', 'kendo', 'core/grid-funcs', 'core/add-menu'], function($, kendo, gridFuncs, addMenu){ ... })
```

The transactions.blade.php file (Laravel):

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

@include('includes.main-menu')

<div id="incomeGrid"></div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="incomeToolBar">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <button class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add pull-right"><span class="k-icon k-add"></span>Add part</button>
    </div>
</script>

@stop

@section('js')
<script>require(['core/transaction-grid'])</script>
@stop
```

How can I get everything to load in the correct order?

---

In transaction-grid.js I am getting this error, so load order was what I thought could be a the problem (kendo not being loaded):

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

With:

```
var activeGrid = $('#incomeGrid');
...
activeGrid.kendoGrid({ ... Error happens here
```

---

grid-funcs.js:

```
define(['jquery', 'kendo'], function ($, kendo) {
...

    return editors;
});
```

Comment: the way require load library does not matter in network , but it must execute the library based on your given dependency. so it can load kendo first than jquery but it will execute jquery first than kendo.

Comment: where is the dependency that "core/grid-funcs" is depend on kendo, you should give than only it will work.

Comment: @PushkerYadav See my edit, I am unsure how it is wrong or causing that error for the line: activeGrid.kendoGrid({ ...

Comment: can you check what is undefined ?

Comment: @PushkerYadav What do you mean?